# Overwrite Azure SQL Server Database through PowerShell commands

Tags: c#, powershell, azure-powershell, pester

I could not find a way how to overwrite an existing database in Azure SQL Server through PowerShell.

Is there any option provided from Microsoft or someone who had this issues how to overwrite again and again the databases...

Here is my code how to copy it, but there is not an option to overwrite the database... any help would appreciate.

```
[String]$tenantId = '' these are filled removed only here
[String]$accountId= ''
[String]$subscriptionId = ''
[String]$databaseServereInstance = ''
[String]$sourceDatabaseName = ''
[String]$azureRg = ''
[String]$sourceServer = ''

Write-Information -MessageData '*** Obtain token and connect to Azure AD ***' 

#Obtain the Access Token
[Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.Models.PSAccessToken]$accessToken = Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl 'https://graph.windows.net/'
[String]$dbAaccessToken = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl 'https://database.windows.net/').Token
Write-Output $dbAaccessToken
#Connect to AzureAD
Connect-AzureAD -AadAccessToken $accessToken.Token -TenantId $tenantId -AccountId $accountId

#Get-AzureADGroup
[String]$groupname = 'test' these are filled removed only
[Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.Group]$getGroup = Get-AzureADGroup | Where { $PSItem.DisplayName -eq $groupname }
Write-Output $getGroup.DisplayName

if($getGroup -ne $null)
{
  #Get-AzureADGroupMember
  Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $getGroup.ObjectId | ForEach-Object -Process `
  {
    [String]$userPrincipalName = $PSItem.UserPrincipalName
    [String]$givenName = $PSItem.GivenName
    [String]$getDbAzSqlAaccessToken = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl 'https://database.windows.net/').Token

     if([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($PSItem.GivenName))
     {
        #Copy source database for each user in a group and make the user db_owner
        New-AzSqlDatabaseCopy -ResourceGroupName $azureRg -ServerName $sourceServer -DatabaseName $sourceDatabaseName `
        -CopyResourceGroupName $azureRg -CopyServerName $sourceServer -CopyDatabaseName "$($sourceDatabaseName)-DevDB-$($userPrincipalName)" 
     
        [String]$query = "
         -- Add contained Azure AD user 
        CREATE USER [$($userPrincipalName)] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo;    
        -- Add user to role(s) in db 
        ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER [$($userPrincipalName)]; 
        "
       
        Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $databaseServereInstance -Database "$($sourceDatabaseName)-DevDB-$($userPrincipalName)" -AccessToken $getDbAzSqlAaccessToken ` -query $query
     }
     else 
     {
        #Copy source database for each user in a group and make the user db_owner
        New-AzSqlDatabaseCopy -ResourceGroupName $azureRg -ServerName $sourceServer -DatabaseName $sourceDatabaseName `
        -CopyResourceGroupName $azureRg -CopyServerName $sourceServer -CopyDatabaseName "$($sourceDatabaseName)-DevDB-$($givenName)" 
     
        [String]$query = "
         -- Add contained Azure AD user 
        CREATE USER [$($givenName)] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo;    
        -- Add user to role(s) in db 
        ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER [$($givenName)]; 
        "
        
        Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $databaseServereInstance -Database "$($sourceDatabaseName)-DevDB-$($givenName)" -AccessToken $getDbAzSqlAaccessToken ` -query $query
     }
   }
} 
else
{
  Write-Verbose -Message "AzureAD Group could not be found..."
}
```

Comment: If you just want to create a new copy with the same DevDB name, then you should probably just `Remove-AzSqlDatabase` before copying.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [Cpt.Whale](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7411885/cpt-whale). Posting your suggestions as answer to help other community members.

To create a new copy of database with the same DB Name then you need to `Remove-AzSqlDatabase`  with the same name then it will be easy to create new one.

Also,
you can even rename the database which will prevent potential data/database changes while renaming and restoring database.

1. Rename the database you want to restore
2. Restore to a new database with the original name

Check the [Overwriting Azure SQL databases](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/94da4d98-1cc6-4817-abd5-674a439d96a8/overwriting-azure-sql-databases-from-quotbackupquot?forum=ssdsgetstarted) for further information.